# Moderncv, Polyglossia and Font

Tags: moderncv, polyglossia

I'm writing my CV using `moderncv` and compiling it in lualatex. When adding `polyglossia`, and more specifically the `\setdefaultlanguage` command to the `.tex` file, the `sans` option in `moderncv` doesn't work anymore. Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Calibri}

\moderncvstyle{classic}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}       
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

This has been reported [elsewhere](https://bugs.launchpad.net/moderncv/+bug/1175526), I can't, however, seem to find if it's been resolved.

Comment: I don't know what happens, but adding `\normalfont` after `\begin{document}` is a workaround.

Comment: Try it with `\usepackage[english]{babel}` instead of `\usepackage{polyglossia}`.

Answer (score 2):

The matter is quite convoluted, but adding `\normalfont` after `\begin{document}` solves the issue.